# Which items are stackable?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Which items are stackable in *Animal Crossing: New Leaf*?

Offhand, I know I can stack fruit, coins and sacks of money. Anything else?

Comment: I feel dumb.  This is the first time I have realised fruit is stackable...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following items can be stacked:

- Money: Up to 99 thousand bells, in stacks of 1000 each, or 900 bells in stacks of 100 each
- Fruit: Up to 9 fruit of the same type. Perfect and possibly rotten fruit must be stacked separately.
- Turnips: Turnips come in batches of 10 and can stack up to 100 per inventory slot (10 stacks)
- Stationary paper: Comes in a pack of 4. I don't believe you can re-stack stationary but I haven't tried.

I'm not aware of any others at the moment.